# What does "ungodly" mean in the following context?

Tags: meaning

What does this sentence mean 
" Tina can’t wait until they stop working such ungodly hours"
Is it mean that she works all the time, except the hour that she sleep!!
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Do you know that you could've easily answered your equation by consulting an online dictionary? If you refer to a time as an ungodly hour, you are emphasizing that it is very early in the morning. That's from [**here**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ungodly). Here's how [**English Oxford Living Dictionaries**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ungodly) defines it:

> (informal) unreasonably early or inconvenient

Example:

> I've been troubled by telephone calls at ungodly hours.

The word itself basically means *inappropriate* or *immoral*—something that God himself would not approve of.

Answer (score 0):

The original answer (going back at least to the publication of the King James Bible) is that it meant something was unlike God.  In context that meant an ungodly action was against God, against God's wishes, or a person who disregarded God's wishes.  It is still used this way in some conservative religious circles.

In contemporary language, it means inconveniently early, as in an ungodly hour of the morning.